# SubSonic 2.2 making template for DBF files

Tags: subsonic, subsonic2.2

I have SubSonic 2.2 and I have some DBF files that I need to use for a project. I'm wondering if it's possible to edit the .aspx templates to work with DBF? Has anyone tried this and have a working template?